# error strtolower function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

The follow error I get when I try to strtolower() my checked in codeigniter.
this is error:

```
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

and

```
 Undefined property: CI_Loader::$unit_id
```

this is my view

```
   <div class="checkbox">
                                        <?php foreach ($unit_list as $unit) :?>
                                        <?php $isChecked = (strtolower($unit->unit_id) == strtolower($unit_id)) ? true : false; ?>
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" checked='$isChecked' name="unit_id[]" value="<?php echo $unit->unit_id ?>"><?php echo $unit->unit_id ?>
                                                </label>""
                                        <?php endforeach?>

                                    </div>
```

this controller

```
$this->data['unit_list']= $this->munit_list->get_all_unit_list2();     

  $fleet = $this->input->post('id_fleet');
                $unit_id = $this->input->post('unit_id');
                $this->data['unit_id']= $unit_id;

                // get shift and date
                $q = $this->database_three->select("*")->from('fleet')->where('id_fleet', $fleet)->limit(1)->get()->row();
                $fleet_date  = $q->date;
                $fleet_shift = $q->shift;

                //$this->db->select('f.*, fm.*')->from('fleet_member as fm, fleet as f');
                        $custom_sql   = "fm.id_fleet = f.id_fleet AND f.date = '$fleet_date' AND f.shift = '$fleet_shift'";
                        $custom_where = "";
                $records = array();

                for ($i=0; $i < count($unit_id) ; $i++) {
                    $records[] = array(
                                        'id_fleet' => $fleet,
                                        'unit_id'  => $unit_id[$i]
                    );
```

model

```
function get_all_unit_list2()
    {
        $this->database_two->order_by('unit_id','desc');
        $data = $this->database_two->query(
            "Select unit_list.unit_id, vehicle_group.vec_type, vehicle_group.vec_group 
            from unit_list, vehicle_group 
            where unit_list.vec_type = vehicle_group.vec_type 
            AND vec_group IN ('OHT','ADT') ");
        return $data->result();
    }
```

can you help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What get_all_unit_list2 function return is it string or object?

Comment: `$this->unit_id` is not anything that will be passed to your controller. Set the unit id in your controller by doing `$this->data['unit_id'] = $unit_id;` instead of `$this->unit_id = $unit_id;` and calling it within your view like this:

`$isChecked = (strtolower($unit->unit_id) == strtolower($unit_id)) ? true : false;`

Comment: @vijay4vijju array(46) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#26

Comment: @RhapX i already changed with $this->data['unit_id']= $unit_id; but still error

Comment: @point did you update your view file?

Comment: If it's still not working after updating your view file, post your updated code.

Comment: i already update and now error massage in view like this  Undefined variable: unit_id

Comment: you can see now, but in view like this Undefined variable: unit_id

Comment: print $unit_list using print_r($unit_list) and see unit_id is a string or object. Please show your print_r($unit_list) response.

Comment: It sounds like `$this->data['unit_id']= $unit_id;` is not getting set which means your `$this->input->post('unit_id')` is not correct (not posting any data). If you echo `$this->input->post('unit_id')` in your controller, do you get any output or does that error?

Comment: when i var_dump($this->input->post('unit_id')), result is array(46) { [0]=> string(5) "CA027" [1]=> string(5) "CA029" [2]

Comment: update your full controller function or the area you calling veiw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can see your code you are not passing $unit_id to view so u got Undefined property:

```
CI_Loader::$unit_id and secondly
```

in your unit_list arrary make sure you are getting data in

```
result() not in resul_array()
```

i mean in you controller when u call

```
get_all_unit_list2()
```

then return should be an object or an array in the form of result()

for example

```
$this->data['unit_list']= $this->munit_list->get_all_unit_list2();
```

now in your model

```
function get_all_unit_list2()
```

you should have a query and return should me like

```
$query= $this->db->get('tablename'); 

return $query->result();
```

now in your view you can use, $unit_list->unit_id if there is result in variable

```
$this->data['unit_list']
```

hopefully this will make it clear.

Comment: in my model is already use return $query->result(); you can see in above

Comment: $fleet = $this->input->post('id_fleet');
 $unit_id = $this->input->post('unit_id');
 $this->data['unit_id']= $unit_id; write this code in controller above $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_fleet', 'ID Fleet', 'required'); and try again.

Comment: i don't want to all data checked.. how?

Comment: all data checked because you used checked="$checked" you must write if ($checked == true) echo 'checked' and your problem will be solved don't use checked="$checked" its wrong so use what i said.

Answer (score 0):

first of all in your view you have following error

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" **checked='$isChecked'** name="unit_id[]" value="<?php echo $unit->unit_id ?>"><?php echo $unit->unit_id ?>

 </label>
```

secondly you are pass same $unit_it from controller in two variables $records[] and $data['unit_id'] now i'm not sure which one you are passing if its $records[] than its an array and in your condition

```
 <?php $isChecked = (strtolower($unit->unit_id) == strtolower(**$unit_id**)) ? true : false; ?>
```

you are using a string so thats why you are getting ci_loader array it expect a string to convert to strtolower but you are passing an object or array

try to resolve these issue after that you will understand because i can't see your complete code which variables you are passing to view .

Regards

Imran Qasim

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting ')'

Comment: don't use * they are just for your reference purposes i just higlighted them so remove them in your code

Comment: just paste here complete function of the controller which passing variables to the above mentioned view your controller is not complete i need to see what are you using in $this->load->view

Comment: i paste again to above or just that link? how?

Comment: i can see your code you are not passing $unit_id to view so u got Undefined property: CI_Loader::$unit_id and secondly in your unit_list arrary make sure you are getting data in result() not in resul_array() i mean in you controller when u call  get_all_unit_list2() then return should be an object or an array in the form of result() for example